# Canonical way to create a NumPy dtype object

Tags: python, numpy

NumPy provides a number of different ways to create dtype objects:

```py
import numpy


# Full name
print(numpy.dtype("uint16"))
# >>> dtype('uint16')

# Short name
print(numpy.dtype("u2"))
# >>> dtype('uint16')

# Scalar type
print(numpy.dtype(numpy.uint16))
# >>> dtype('uint16')

# Format char from the "struct" module
print(numpy.dtype("H"))
# >>> dtype('uint16')
```

What is *the canonical and recommended way* to do it?

Comment: What's your purpose?  All of those work.  I only use `np.dtype` to make a compound dtype for a structured array.

Comment: Btw, `np.int`, `np.float` and others are [deprecating](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html)

Comment: I usually use `np.uint16` and such, because the names are most self-documenting to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for:

```
In [45]: np.uint16?
Init signature: np.uint16(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
Unsigned integer type, compatible with C ``unsigned short``.
Character code: ``'H'``.
Canonical name: ``np.ushort``.
Alias *on this platform*: ``np.uint16``: 16-bit unsigned integer (0 to 65535).
File:           /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py
Type:           type
```

`np.uint16` is actually a function that can create a numpy array or scalar

```
In [50]: np.uint16([1,2,3])
Out[50]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)
In [51]: type(np.uint16(12))
Out[51]: numpy.uint16
In [52]: np.uint16(12)
Out[52]: 12
```

`np.dtype` is set up to parse/understand a variety of strings.  Note the `character code` and `canonical name` in the doc.  `np.ushort` is also a function.

```
In [56]: np.ushort([1,2,3])
Out[56]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)
```

I'm not sure there is a "Canonical" or preferred form among the string alternatives.

```
Out[56]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)
In [57]: np.array([1,2,3], 'u2')
Out[57]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)
In [58]: np.array([1,2,3], 'H')
Out[58]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)
In [59]: np.array([1,2,3], 'ushort')
Out[59]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

```
In [64]: np.typecodes
Out[64]: 
{'Character': 'c',
 'Integer': 'bhilqp',
 'UnsignedInteger': 'BHILQP',
 'Float': 'efdg',
 'Complex': 'FDG',
 'AllInteger': 'bBhHiIlLqQpP',
 'AllFloat': 'efdgFDG',
 'Datetime': 'Mm',
 'All': '?bhilqpBHILQPefdgFDGSUVOMm'}

In [65]: np.typeDict
Out[65]: 
{'?': numpy.bool_,
 0: numpy.bool_,
 'byte': numpy.int8,
 'b': numpy.int8,
 1: numpy.int8,
 'ubyte': numpy.uint8,
 'B': numpy.uint8,
  ...
```

Note that multibyte character codes may also have byte order indicators, e.g. `<H` and `>H`.  We don't usually use those, but sometimes when working with binary files from other languages we need them.